# Is there a way to render svg data in a swf at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, svg

I'd like to render to svg data in a swf at runtime (not in Flex - not using degrafa) - how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ajaxian blog had a post about this today.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-state-of-svg-browser-support-using-flash-for-svg-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 2):

If ActionScript 2:

Use the **com.itechnica.svg** (PathToArray) library to load SVGs at SWF runtime and display them *(uses XML for SVG parsing)*:

[Using **SVG Path Data** in Flash](http://flash-creations.com/notes/sample_svgtoflash.php), Code download button on the **right pane.**

---

If ActionScript 3:

Use the  **com.zavoo.svg** (SvgPath) library to load SVGs at SWF runtime and display them *(uses RegExp for SVG parsing)*:

[Source code for **SvgLoad** and **SvgDraw**](http://labs.zavoo.com/content/flex/DrawSvg/srcview/index.html), Code download button on the **bottom-left.**